# How to get cursor position in TextInput when I change value by using my custom keyboard. React-Native

Tags: react-native

I can get cursor position by using onSelectionChange, its work perfectly when i change value by using default keyboard. But when I use my custom keyboard, which just change value prop on TextInput. onSelectionChange event doesn't trigger at all. How I can use custom keyboard and know cursor position?
SandBox with problem: https://snack.expo.dev/@homebake/selectedchange-problem?platform=ios

onSelectionChange triggered only if user manually change selection, after change value, cursor moved, but selection doesn't change. I create variable with selection and every time when user add new character, I add 1 to this variable, and -1 if delete. If user change selection manually onSelectionChange triggered and change this variable. Its work, but i don't like this because i have mask on my Input. Not every time I need to add position just 1.

I need any tips how I can use custom keyboard with TextInput and know cursor position. Even if it's possible without onSelectionChange.